# Moving Files from One HDfs Directory to Another using Pyspark

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I am reading this some files from hdfs ,processing by pyspark and writing back to new hdfs location.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
InputPath = "/user/test/Input/"
OutputPath = "/user/test/Output/"
ArchivePath = "/user/test/Archive/"
session = SparkSession.builder().appName("appName").master("local").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.format("json").option("inferSchema", "true").option("multiLine", "true").load(InputPath)
          .withColumn("current_date_col",current_date())
df.write.mode("append").parquet(OutputPath)
```

Now I want to move the processed files from hdfs InputPath to Archive Path. Is there any way to modify above code so it can move from InputPath to Archive after Writing at OutputPath.

I tried Writing below code but its not moving the file and showing boolean: false

```
val file_target = new Path(ArchivePath)
val file_source = new Path(InputPath)
fs.rename(file_source, file_target)
```

Comment: SparkSQL doesn't really move files, no. You can import the HDFS API in Pyspark, by the way, you shouldn't need Scala. Otherwise, make sure you are importing the Hadoop Path object, not the Java one

Comment: @OneCricketeer
 yes I am not doing it with sparksql

Answer (score 0):

Below Code Worked for me.

```
import subprocess
InputPath = "/user/test/InputPath/*.json"
ArchivePath = "/user/test/ArchivePath/"
proc = subprocess.Popen(["hdfs", "dfs", "-mv", InputPath, ArchivePath])
proc.communicate()
```

Comment: This answer requires hdfs binary to be available... Again, you should be able to import Filesystem class from Pyspark. https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/accessing-hadoop-filesystem-api-with-pyspark-29cff901de51